# How to call VS Code Editor from terminal / command line

Tags: command-line, terminal, visual-studio-code, text-editor

The question says it all.

How can I open VS Code editor from

- windows cmd
- linux and mac terminal

e.g. for notepad++ I write

`> start notepad++ test.txt`

By the way, the editor is awesome (cross-platform)! Thank you Nadella!

You can download it from [microsoft](https://code.visualstudio.com/)

Comment: On run prompt or command shell prompt just type - `code -n "D:\myTextFile.txt"` and get going.

Comment: `code ./search.pl` worked for me on windows 7 in visual studios own terminal

Comment: `code -n filename` -- Opens file in NEW window.

`code -r filename` -- Opens file in already opened window (this is what I wanted and why I'm commenting. It works great from the terminal window of VSCode).

`code -g filename` -- Handy! As you can see from running `code --help`, the -g flag is short for `--goto` and it is my favorite command to use when debugging. You can use just the file name and it acts just like `-r` OR, you can use `<file:line[:character]>` to go straight to a line, or even char on a line!

Comment: In case someone needs for Mac: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zWfNLB_CBFs

Answer (score 382, accepted):

To open a file or directory use the command:

```
code /path/to/file/or/directory/you/want/to/open
```

**For macOS users**, it needs to be installed manually:

1. Launch VS Code.
2. `Command + Shift + P` to open the Command Palette.
3. Type `shell command`, to find the `Shell Command: Install 'code' command in PATH` and select to install it.
4. Restart your terminal.

Comment: Was looking for this to set vscode as diff-tool. You can use `code -d file1 file2` to compare files.

Comment: I am on Windows and this most definitely does not work for me.

Comment: @ChristopherHarris if you're using the insiders build then it command is `code-insiders`

Comment: the docs explain everything: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line

Comment: This command is straight up missing for me in VS Code 1.22.2 non-insiders.

Comment: I have tried this fix multiple times. It just goes vanishes when I restart the terminal, or maybe when I restart the computer.

Answer (score 83):

Per the [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/setup):

> #### Mac OS X
>
> 1. Download Visual Studio Code for Mac OS X.
> 2. Double-click on VSCode-osx.zip to expand the contents.
> 3. Drag Visual Studio Code.app to the Applications folder, making it available in the Launchpad.
> 4. Add VS Code to your Dock by right-clicking on the icon and choosing Options, Keep in Dock.
>
> **Tip**: If you want to run VS Code from the terminal, append the following to your ~/.bash_profile file (~/.zshrc in case you use zsh).
>
> ```
> code () { VSCODE_CWD="$PWD" open -n -b "com.microsoft.VSCode" --args $* ;}
> ```
>
> Now, you can simply type code . in any folder to start editing files
>   in that folder.
>
> **Tip**: You can also add it to VS Code Insiders build by changing "com.microsoft.VSCodeInsiders". Also if you don't to type the whole word code, just change it to c.
>
> #### Linux
>
> 1. Download Visual Studio Code for Linux.
> 2. Make a new folder and extract VSCode-linux-x64.zip inside that folder.
> 3. Double click on Code to run Visual Studio Code.
>
> **Tip**: If you want to run VS Code from the terminal, create the following link substituting /path/to/vscode/Code with the absolute
>   path to the Code executable
>
> ```
> sudo ln -s /path/to/vscode/Code /usr/local/bin/code
> ```
>
> Now, you can simply type code . in any folder to start editing files
>   in that folder.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I think you forget to paste the window case.

Comment: Windows is automatically added when you install it.

Comment: Per the docs, you can now install it on Mac via the Command Palette (Cmd-Shift-P), `Shell Command: Install 'code' in PATH`

Comment: On Mac, this works, but will open a different instance of VS Code than the shortcut installed from the command palette. (I noticed I was running two versions simultaneously after adding and trying the above Mac shell code—and the filename search was much slower in the version opened by the manually installed shortcut.)

Comment: Is there a reason you used `$*` instead of `"${@}"`? [[ref](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-_0040)]

Answer (score 32):

VS Code is a must have code editor for 2018

For Windows 10 users a lot is possible, the same way the Mac OS users type  `code .` .

Look for you VS Code \bin folder path e.g `C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin` . The bin folder includes a file called  `code.cmd` .

If you are not sure about what is your path, type `where code.cmd`, and then, copy it without the `\code.cmd` after the `...\bin`.

Follow the steps below and be proud of the OS you use.

1. Search for "Advanced System Setting" from Start.
2. Click on Environment Variables.
3. On System Variables choose "path" from Variable tab and click on Edit.
4. Click on New on the right side of the popup window.
5. Copy your path from the Explorer's breadcrumb path and paste it into the new opened path in step 4, example:- `C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin`.
6. Click Ok on all the open windows to confirm changes and restart your  `cmd` .
7. Go to your  `cmd`  and navigate to you working directory on server and type  `code .`  .

`C:>cd wamp64\www\react-app> code .` to open with VS Code on Windows.

Visual Studio Code also includes a command prompt (terminal) window and you can open one or more of them with: 
`` Ctrl + ` ``  on your keyboard.

Hope this helps some one like it did to many of us.

Comment: The files and folder structure has changed for the newer versions of VS Code (Windows). So, `code.cmd` was not available. BUT, the `code` command was added to PATH by default since installation

Comment: For anyone else - what @Kathir says above is not true for me.  Was not in my path, and bin directory still contains `code.cmd` for me.  I first tried to do this with `code.exe`, but it's kind of a pain, because by default, it dumps everything into the terminal and runs as an ongoing terminal process.

Comment: The Terminal should be restarted after step No. 6 so the new `PATH` values take effect.

Answer (score 22):

You can also run VS Code from the terminal by typing `code` after adding it to the path:

Launch VS Code.
Open the Command Palette `(⇧⌘P)` and type `shell command` to find the Shell Command: Install `code` command in PATH command.
Mac shell commands

Restart the terminal for the new `$PATH` value to take effect. You'll be able to type `code .` in any folder to start editing files in that folder.

Comment: This is the right answer for mac and least hacky of all solutions

Answer (score 8):

## For VS Code Insiders Windows users ([vs code doc](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/windows)):

Add the directory `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code Insiders\bin"`
at %PATH% environmental variable.

then go to the folder that you want to open with vs code and type:
 **`code-insders .`**

Answer (score 7):

Sometimes setting path from VS Code command palette does not work

Instead manually add your VS Code to your path:

1. Run in terminal

   `sudo nano /etc/paths`
2. Go to the bottom of the file, and enter the path you wish to add
3. Hit control-x to quit. Enter “Y” to save the modified buffer.
4. Restart your terminal and to test `echo $PATH`. You should something similar

`~ echo $PATH /Users/shashank/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.2/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin`

Next time, you navigate to your project folder from terminal

#### Enter:

`code .`

#### or

`code /path/to/project`

[Source](http://www.architectryan.com/2012/10/02/add-to-the-path-on-mac-os-x-mountain-lion/#.Wj02g1T1XOR)

Answer (score 6):

In the case of Linux and Mac, you want to navigate to the directory that you extracted the VSCode files using the 'cd' command.  For example:

```
cd ~/Downloads/VSCode
```

Then you start the application by running..

```
./Code
```

'Code' being the name of the executable.

If you have root access on the machine, you can configure the system to allow you to start VSCode from anywhere by linking it to /usr/bin, where links to executables are often stored.

```
sudo ln -s /path/to/VSCode/folder/Code /usr/bin/Code
```

You can now launch VSCode from anywhere by typing:

```
Code
```

Comment: In Mac it is actually a folder ```Visual Studo Code.app``` so, we cant make the ln -s

Comment: This is precisely how not to do it. The answers given below by Laily and others are correct.

Comment: this does not work for mac. the process does not go to background and also gets permission issues.

Comment: this solution is help me in pop-os thank you very mush

Answer (score 6):

For command line heads you can also run

`sudo ln -s "/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/code" /usr/local/bin/code`

this will do the exact same thing as the `Shell Command: Install 'code' command in PATH command` feature in VSCode.

Answer (score 4):

When installing on Windows, you will be prompted to add VS Code to your PATH.

I was trying to figure out how to open files with VS Code from the command line and I already had the capability - I just forgot I had already added it. You might already have it installed - check by navigating to a folder you want to open and running the command `code .` to open that folder.

Answer (score 4):

In linux if you use `code .` it will open VS Code in the folder the terminal was in.
Using `code . Filename.cs` it will open in folder and open said file.

Answer (score 3):

For linux Debian the below can be done

```
$ export PATH=$PATH:/usr/share/code
```

Then run it

```
$ code
$ code file.py
$ code workingdir
```

Answer (score 2):

On Windows you can add the following path to the system environment variables.

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin
```

Answer (score 2):

Open command line and type:

```
cd your_folder_path
code.cmd .
```

or

```
code.cmd your_folder_path
```

It will open your folder in Visual Studio Code.
Make Sure, you are inside the correct folder after executing "cd your_folder_path" command.

Answer (score 1):

This works for Windows:

```
CMD> start vscode://file/o:/git/libzmq/builds/msvc/vs2017/libzmq.sln
```

But if the filepath has spaces, normally one would add double quotes around it, like this:

```
CMD> start "vscode://file/o:/git/lib zmq/builds/msvc/vs2017/libzmq.sln"
```

But this messes up with start, which can take a double-quoted title, so it will create a window with this name as the title and not open the project.

```
CMD> start "title" "vscode://file/o:/git/lib zmq/builds/msvc/vs2017/libzmq.sln"
```

Answer (score 1):

typing "code" in dos command prompt worked for me

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu the flatpak version seemed broken.  I uninstalled it and downloaded the deb package right from Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following command to load a project quickly (in linux)

1. cd into the project `cd /project`
2. run command `code pwd`

similar steps can be used in other Os too.

Answer (score 1):

In linux terminal you can just type:

`$ code run`

Answer (score 1):

Windows:

Add  **code CLI** path in a system environment variable.

in windows default code cli path is (username is you pc username)`C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin`

[image]

Then you can check it like this by taking your project folder and open new cmd and type `code .`

[image]

Comment: This is the correct answer if you're looking for Windows solution.

Answer (score 0):

This will work.   This is your directory name   "Directory_Name"

```
 sudo code --user-data-dir="Directory_Name"
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: create a .bat file with the name you want e.g vscode.bat 
Step 2: Write your path to Visual Studio Code 
Step 3: Save it in C:\Windows\System32 directory

```
**
C:
cd Users\Bino\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
Code.exe**
```

Step 4: You can call visual studio code from any where by typing "vscode" which is the name of your bat file

Answer (score 0):

Other easyway to do it on mac is :go to Command Palette[ Shift ⇧+ Command (⌘)+P] and type :Shell Command: Install 'code' command in PATH

once installed: Shell command 'code' successfully installed in PATH.

Then you can use code from the terminal as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you install VS CODE using `snap`. You will need to add `/snap/bin` in your `PATH` environment variable.
so - open your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`
and add `:/snap/bin` in your PATH environment variable
reload terminal,
and than `code` comand will start it

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to go to your Project where you want to open it and type

> code.cmd D:\PathTo\yourProject\MyProject

[image]

That's it. It will open your project in Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 0):

Delete old virtual environment and create a fresh virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

*In a way I am reticent to add to the long list of answers.  However, I searched this page for the word "portable" and came up empty.  (And I did a full Stack Overflow search and also found nothing.)  So I want to add this very specific answer for potential future searchers.*

This answer is for if you installed VS Code in **Portable Mode** on Windows 10.

"Portable Mode" refers to what is described on the official VS Code web pages, which as of 21 January 2021 are found here: https://code.visualstudio.com.  It does not mean the Visual Studio Code Portable project started/run by  Gareth Flowers, or any similar project.  (I am not saying anything bad about this or other projects - I have neither used nor evaluated.)  If you are using one of those projects, you need to check with that project documentation/community - although this might work.

"Installing" VS Code in Portable Mode is downloading a *.zip* archive and extracting it locally wherever you want your VS Code "installation" to live.  There is no actual installation or setup that is run, so there is no automatic adding of the `code` command to your `PATH`.

---

#### Answer

After extracting the **Portable Mode VS Code** files to the location of your choice, there should be a `bin` folder in that location.  Copy the full path of that `bin` folder and add it to your System or User (your choice) `PATH` variable.

You should then be able to use the `code` command from PowerShell or CMD.

Answer (score 0):

In linux you need to check first what is the name you your vscode  binary file

When you get the binary file name check where it is by using this command :
whereis your_file_name

Go to the / (root) and go to bin and rename file with any name what you want to call it.
To rename : mv your_file_name your_changed_name
Now you can access vscode from any where in terminal

This works on Debian based Os definitely

Answer (score 0):

### For Mac OS:

Inside Visual Studio Code press:

```
Command + Shift + P
```

Type: `shell` and select it:

[image]

Once you hit enter, you're all done.

[image]

Full article: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-open-visual-studio-code-from-your-terminal/