# Run / Open VSCode from Mac Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, visual-studio-code

I'd like to run / open Visual Studio Code from the Mac OSX Terminal by running this command `code .`.  I found instructions here:

https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/setup

Apparently I need to include this in my `.bashrc` file, so I did, but to no avail.

```
code () {
    if [[ $# = 0 ]]
    then
        open -a "Visual Studio Code"
    else
        [[ $1 = /* ]] && F="$1" || F="$PWD/${1#./}"
        open -a "Visual Studio Code" --args "$F"
    fi
}
```

I edited the `.bashrc` file here:

`~/.bashrc` which points to `/Users/username/.bashrc`

Which `.bashrc` should I be editing?

Comment: have you sourced the .bashrc after adding the function? `$ source ~/.bashrc`. I would suggest you to source the `.bashrc` from `~/.bash_profile`.

Comment: In `OS X` you would generally add that to your `~/.bash_profile` — not `~/.bashrc` then restart `Terminal.app` or source it like mentioned.

Comment: l'L'l is right, adding the snippet to .bash_profile works

Comment: You were all right.  It was bash_profile.  Thank you!

Comment: Has anyone else had the issue that this works for the "first" thing you open - but once Visual Studio Code is launched, you can't open "other" files from terminal using this technique ?

Comment: With VS Code 0.3.0 we recommend to use a different syntax for the code command. This new syntax supports multiple arguments and correctly identifies the current working directory: code () {
    VSCODE_CWD="$PWD" open -n -b "com.microsoft.VSCode" --args $*
}

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36882426/1374488) should be the correct answer.

Comment: pple in 2017 pls see @kylebrandt's comment to the answer below

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call VS Code Editor from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29963617/how-to-call-vs-code-editor-from-command-line)

Comment: Explained precisely in couple of mins: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zWfNLB_CBFs

Answer (score 2631, accepted):

According to the docs on [Launching from the command line](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/mac#_launching-from-the-command-line):

1. Open Visual Studio Code
2. Open the command pallette with <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> (or <kbd>F1</kbd>)
3. Type `Shell` in command palette
4. Select `Shell Command: Install code in PATH` from suggested list

[image: Open VSCode via Terminal/Command Prompt]

That's it.

Now open your terminal type.

```
$ code .
```

---

### To make this change persist after restart on MacOS

Many Mac users find this is forgotten and needs to be re-applied after any restart. This may happen if MacOS has applied the quarantine attribute to VS Code, which the OS uses for the "Are you sure?" notice applied on first using apps downloaded from the internet.

To check if this attribute is applied, look for `com.apple.quarantine` in the list returned by this command (changing the path if that's not where you installed it):

```
xattr "/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app"
```

If that does return `com.apple.quarantine`, you can remove the attribute using the same command with the `-d` flag (alongside `-r` to recursively remove it from all contained files and `sudo` to allow the change):

```
sudo xattr -r -d com.apple.quarantine "/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app"
```

...then do `Shell Command : Install code in PATH` as above after the attribute has been removed, and it should persist after restart.

*Credit: [derflounder.wordpress.com article](https://derflounder.wordpress.com/2012/11/20/clearing-the-quarantine-extended-attribute-from-downloaded-applications) linked to by [RicardoVallejo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3429457/ricardovallejo) in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30065227/run-open-vscode-from-mac-terminal#comment95469686_36882426).*

---

Comment: this works not by updating PATH with full path to reach VSCode, instead it introduces a symlink  `/usr/local/bin/code@ -> /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/code`  which coming from a linux background seems strange yet I guess this is how OSX rolls

Comment: For anyone experiencing the loss of the "code ." command when restarting, then you may have the code program as quarantine.
https://derflounder.wordpress.com/2012/11/20/clearing-the-quarantine-extended-attribute-from-downloaded-applications

Comment: @RZKY Do you have any reference? I'm still seeing those command in v1.44.2

Comment: Works as expected. OS X 10.15.4

Comment: I've just ```ln -s "/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/code" /usr/local/bin/vscode```

Comment: How come this doesn't persist, I have to do this after every restart

Comment: @CezarCobuz I've [editted in a section](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/36882426/11) on how to avoid needing to re-do this after restart, based on [the link](https://derflounder.wordpress.com/2012/11/20/clearing-the-quarantine-extended-attribute-from-downloaded-applications) in [RicardoVallejo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3429457/ricardovallejo)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30065227/run-open-vscode-from-mac-terminal#comment95469686_36882426) above.

Comment: @ScottStensland they certainly do that so it works on any shell (Bash, zsh, ...) and don't take the risk to break your config. It also works for all users.

Comment: I used to manually create symlink for `code` till today realise this can be done much easier. thx.

Comment: Thanks, It works for me on version mac 11.6.1 Big Sur

Comment: doesn't macos use zsh by default? so shouldn't the op be adding those lines to their `~/.zshrc?`?

Comment: getting this even with sudo `xattr: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents'`

Answer (score 85):

I just want to pull out Benjamin Pasero's answer from inside his comment as it seems the best solution. It is the tip given on the [Setting up Visual Studio Code page](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/setup) where it says ...

If you want to run VS Code from the terminal, append the following to your ~/.bash_profile file (~/.zshrc in case you use zsh).

```bash
code () { VSCODE_CWD="$PWD" open -n -b "com.microsoft.VSCode" --args $* ;}
```

Now, you can simply type `code .` in any folder to start editing files in that folder. [Or `code test.txt` to go to work on the `test.txt` file]

Comment: what I love about this method is that I can use "vscode" instead of "code" to launch vscode.

Comment: this uses function instead of alias. function is a better way because you can overwrite (redefine) function without having to undefine it first.

Comment: I like how simple this is; and requires no other steps, like the accepted answer does.

Answer (score 64):

To setup path permanently for mac users;

open `~/.zshrc` using the below command

```
vi ~/.zshrc
```

Add the following path

```
export PATH="$PATH:/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin"
```

And source it using below command

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

Now close the terminal and reopen and run `code .` command should work properly.

Comment: Did not work for me

Comment: Check for the path. May be different for your system.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks!
You can also open the file just with open from the root folder.
ie
open .zshrc

Comment: You don't need to close the terminal if you source the config file

Comment: Update: Rather than `source zshrc`, the new recommended zshrc restart is `exec ~/.zshrc` https://batsov.com/articles/2022/09/15/reload-zsh-configuration/

Answer (score 35):

follow some simple steps :

1. open your visual studio code (vs code).
2. press F1.
3. pallete will open in top center with symbol >
4. type shell .
5. select install 'code' command in PATH.
6. it will be automatically intalled.

Now you can use from terminal by typing

$ code .

Comment: Simplest answer from all above!

Comment: nice one! Simple and effective

Answer (score 23):

Open VSCode, press Command + Shift + P, type Shell in command palette, Select that option => Install code in PATH from suggested list in command palette.

Answer (score 22):

If you are on Mac OSX Maverick,
it's `~/.bash_profile` not `~/.bashrc`

Try putting the code in there, close the terminal and then try again. Should be working

Comment: This is no longer the up to date method, use the instructions in http://stackoverflow.com/a/36882426/107156 instead. This is now a built-in feature to code, and you just have to tell it to install it for you.

Comment: thanks @KyleBrandt for posting the updated instructions

Answer (score 20):

**For macOS 12.0 and above:**

1. Open profile in Notepad

```sh
open ~/.zshrc
```

2. Create an alias for `code`, Paste below:

```sh
alias code='open -a "Visual Studio Code"' # open file or folder in VSCode e.g. code ~/.zshrc
```

3. Now you can open the current folder e.g. `code .` or any other file/folder by providing its path.
4. Profit

---

PS: You can add as many aliases as needed to open a file/folder with different editors. Just mention the editor's name in the alias. For example, open file/folder with sublime text:

```sh
alias subl='open -a "Sublime Text"' # open file or folder in sublime e.g. subl ~/.zshrc
```

And use it like `subl .`

Comment: I prefer this solution since I did not care to overwrite my existing $PATH variable.

Comment: Good! Worked for me and I didn't have to mess with the $PATH

Answer (score 19):

For Mac you can do :
View > Command Palette >  Shell command > "install code command in path". I'd assume there would be something similar for other OS's. After I do

```
which code
```

and it tells me it put it in /usr/local/bin

Comment: This answer doesn't answer the question exactly, but this command is a good addition to my knowledge of commands. This is very helpful to find the source of any command that we use.

Comment: My thought was ... as long as I can type `code` and it launches from the terminal that'll do for me. I used which to see where it put it. Had it not worked automatically I would have gone editing profiles etc. I like the 'kiss' rule ;-)

Answer (score 17):

Sometimes, just adding the shell command doesn't work. We need to check whether visual studio code is available in "Applications" folder or not. That was the case for me.

The moment you download VS code, it stays in "Downloads" folder and terminal doesn't pick up from there. So, I manually moved my VS code to "Applications" folder to access from Terminal.

Step 1: Download VS code, which will give a zipped folder.

Step 2: Run it, which will give a exe kinda file in downloads folder.

Step 3: Move it to "Applications" folder manually.

Step 4: Open VS code, "Command+Shift+P" and run the shell command.

Step 5: Restart the terminal.

Step 6: Typing "Code ." on terminal should work now.

Answer (score 16):

Open **Visual Studio Code** application:

- Open the command palette with <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>
- Type `> Shell` in the command palette
- From the suggested list, select: **Shell Command: Install code in PATH**

Open **Terminal** application:

- Type `code .` in mac terminal

Answer (score 15):

To set up VS code path permanently on Mac OS;

just open .bash_profile using the following command on terminal

```
open -t .bash_profile
```

Then add the following path to .bash_profile

```
code () { VSCODE_CWD="$PWD" open -n -b "com.microsoft.VSCode" --args $* ;}
```

save the .bash_profile file and quit the terminal. Then reopen the terminal and type `code .`to open VS code.

Comment: Great answer. To add a tip: If you don't want to restart the terminal, after you edit the .bash_profile run `source ~/.bash_profile` and it reloads the latest configuration in the current terminal.

Answer (score 14):

Somehow using Raja's approach worked for me only once, after a reboot, it seems gone.
To make it persistent across Mac OS reboot, I added this line into my `~/.zshrc` since I'm using zsh:

`export PATH=/Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin:$PATH`
then

`source ~/.zshrc`
now, I could just do

`code .`

even after I reboot my Mac.

Comment: Does not work after closing and opening terminal. Works only for one session

Comment: Official Documentation works properly suggested by @Raja Jaganathan

Answer (score 13):

For Mac users:

One thing that made the accepted answer not work for me is that I didn't drag the vs code package into the applications folder

**So you need to drag it to the applications folder** then you run the command inside vs code (shown below) [as per the official document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/mac)

- Launch VS Code.
- Open the Command Palette (⇧⌘P) and type 'shell command' to find the
  Shell Command: Install 'code' command in PATH command.

Answer (score 8):

Yo do this:

1. Launch Visual Studio Code.
2. Press Cmd ⌘ + Shift ⇧ + P to open the Command Palette.
3. Type in shell command and select the Shell command: Install ‘code’ command in PATH to install it.

Comment: shell is not in the list

Answer (score 7):

How about a simple Bash alias that you stick in your .bash_profile ?

> alias code="open -a /Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app"

To open the current directory:

> code .

Answer (score 4):

I follow this step it work for me .

first open VSC .
open terminal of VSC.

Press `cmd+shift+p`

**uninstall path .**
Give permission to it.

Press `cmd+shift+p`

**install path .**

then open Mac terminal navigate to root project file
type

**code .** in root folder It will open VSC .  :)

Answer (score 3):

I just made a symbolic link from the "code" program supplied in the Visual Studio Code.app bundle to /usr/local/bin (a place where I prefer to put stuff like that and which is already in my path on my machine).

You can make a symbolic link using ln -s like this:

`ln -s /Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/code /usr/local/bin/code`

Answer (score 2):

To set it up, launch VS Code. Then open the Command Palette (⇧⌘P) and type shell command to find the Shell Command: Install 'code' command in PATH command.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BC0j8.png)

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/mac

Comment: How does this differ from the highest voted answer already here?

Answer (score 2):

add below snipped in your bash profile -

```
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:${PATH}"
code () { VSCODE_CWD="$PWD" open -n -b "com.microsoft.VSCode" --args $* ;}
```

Answer (score 2):

I moved VS Code from Downloads folder to Applications, and then i was able to run code in the terminal. I guess, it might help you too.

Answer (score 2):

1. Open VSCode
2. Go to view --> Command Palette
3. Search for "shell...install 'code'
4. Open your terminal and place in the directory you wanna open
5. Use $ code .

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I simply created a file called code:

```
#!/bin/bash

open /Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app $1
```

Make it executable:

```
$ chmod 755 code
```

Then put that in /usr/local/bin

```
$ sudo mv code /usr/local/bin
```

As long as the file sits someplace that is in your path you can open a file by just typing: code

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to have symlinks in the home directory, in this case at least. Here's how I have things setup:

```
: cat ~/.bash_profile | grep PATH
# places ~/bin first in PATH
export PATH=~/bin:$PATH
```

So I symlinked to the VSCode binary like so:

```
ln -s /Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/code ~/bin/code
```

Now I can issue `code .` in whichever directory I desire.

Answer (score 1):

Since, default shell is `zsh` in macOS, you can try this:

```
cat << EOF >> ~/.zshrc
# Add Visual Studio Code (code)
export PATH="\$PATH:/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin"
EOF
```

This will add a path to your VS Code, restart your terminal and voila, you're good to go.

> code example.py

Answer (score 1):

```
alias code="/Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code\ 2.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/code $1"
```

the alias to the vs code's bin file with parameters works well

you can do `code .` after having sourced your bash file

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the Shell Install PATH does not work.
So, I ran the Uninstall command and then run the install command again.
Now it works well.

Answer (score 0):

open finder and go to applications and make sure that vscode exists there ,then open type in terminal export PATH="/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin"

Answer (score 0):

you can manually add VS Code to your path, to do so run the following commands:

```
cat << EOF >> ~/.bash_profile
# Add Visual Studio Code (code)
export PATH="\$PATH:/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin"
EOF
```

Start a new terminal to pick up your .bash_profile changes.

Note: The leading slash \ is required to prevent $PATH from expanding during the concatenation. Remove the leading slash if you want to run the export command directly in a terminal.

Note: Since zsh became the default shell in macOS Catalina, run the following commands to add VS Code to your path:

```
cat << EOF >> ~/.zprofile
# Add Visual Studio Code (code)
export PATH="\$PATH:/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin"
EOF
```

Answer (score -1):

```
code () {
    if [[ $# = 0 ]]
    then
        open -a "Visual Studio Code"
    else
        echo "Opening: "$@
        "/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron" $@
    fi
}
```

I put that into my `.bash_profile` I tested it and it works.