# Open VSCode from Terminal - Conflict with Parallels VSCode version

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, parallels

Following this [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30065227/run-open-vscode-from-mac-terminal), I was able to add code to my `.bash_profile` so that VSCode opens from the Terminal. However, it is the wrong VSCode that opens.

See, I have Parallels installed on my Mac, and that version of Parallels has a VSCode installed on it. When I run the Terminal command from the post mentioned above, Parallels is launched (even if not opened), and then the VSCode on it opens.

I would like to make sure that it's the VSCode installed on my Mac that opens. At this time, I am still using the Sublime CLI because the VSCode ones are of no use to me in this condition.

What would be my options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to achieve this I found was to disable sharing of Windows apps with Mac:

[image]