# use vscode command in terminal No such file or directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

when I use code command, I get the error

```
$ code 2to3
/usr/local/bin/code: line 10: Loading sentinel dylib...
Successfuly loaded sentinel.dylib.
/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron: No such file or directory
```

Comment: When you look in your `Applications` folder, is VSCode in there?

Comment: YES, the path /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron is exit

Answer (score 0):

Just add the VSCode `bin` path to the `path` environment variable.

The path showing in my Windows system is `C:\Users\sas\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin`

For Mac follow this [Run / Open VSCode from Mac Terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30065227/run-open-vscode-from-mac-terminal)