# How to open VS Code through Commamnd Prompt?

Tags: visual-studio-code, command-prompt

How to open VS Code through Commamnd Prompt ? by typing code. & Enter?
Can anyone help me to setup this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run / Open VSCode from Mac Terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30065227/run-open-vscode-from-mac-terminal)

Answer (score 1):

Typing `code` in my cmd opens VSCode for me. If that doesn't work for you try setting up enviroment variables.

Answer (score 0):

A better way to open VS Code using command prompt:
Go on your folder you can see like this [image: See on image]

a single left click on folder directory

now write

> cmd

command prompt open on your PC,
Now write

> code .

and hit enter

VS code open with your working folder