# PATH is incorrect when using macOS and zsh

Tags: visual-studio-code

When opening vscode from command line on macOS, PATH environment variable get duplicated entries

Steps to reproduce:

1. close vscode ⌘+Q
2. on your terminal: code . -n
3. on a terminal opened on vscode: echo $PATH
4. you'll find that your env PATH has duplicated entries

I saw https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/133012 and https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/149135

Both are pointing to a page that doesn't exist anymore

Others things that I tried [Run / Open VSCode from Mac Terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30065227/run-open-vscode-from-mac-terminal/36882426)

I'm not using insiders and it's happening since I got a mac

[Run / Open VSCode from Mac Terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30065227/run-open-vscode-from-mac-terminal/36882426)
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/133012
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/149135

Comment: This has nothing to do with VS Code.  `PATH` is set in your .zshrc file.  If it's wrong, edit that file to fix it.

Comment: is there no duplication in the `PATH` variable in the terminal where you launch VS Code _from_? And do you observe any difference if you set the `terminal.integrated.shellIntegration.enabled` to `false`?

Comment: "terminal.integrated.shellIntegration.enabled": "false" didn't work

Comment: in fact, vscode is started from a zsh terminal that has been initialized and carries env vars to vscode process. the vscode process start a new zsh terminal that inherits previous initialization like env vars values

Comment: I also tried "terminal.integrated.inheritEnv": false with no lucky