# "Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found." when running "code ."

Tags: .net, bash, visual-studio-code, terminal, path

When I run "code ." in my terminal to open VScode I get the following message:

"Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found.
Possible reasons for this include:

- You misspelled a built-in dotnet command.
- You intended to execute a .NET program, but dotnet-/usr/local/bin/code does not exist.
- You intended to run a global tool, but a dotnet-prefixed executable with this name could not be found on the PATH."

I am working on macOS version Sonoma 14.2.1

I have tried reinstalling .NET and checking the versions of it and ensured the PATH configuration (I’m still not sure if that is actually right) and verified the exicutable location. What am I missing?

Comment: You see something like "C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/bin" in your path variables?

Comment: Which operating system are you using? Also which method did you use to install VS Code ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @TimothyG. when I run echo $PATH I get the following: /Library/PostgreSQL/13/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Applications/VMwareFusion.app/Contents/Public:/usr/local/share/dotnet:~/.dotnet/tools:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin

Comment: @JFT macOS version Sonoma 14.2.1 and I tried to uninstall and reinstall VScode by dowloading the zip file on their homepage

Comment: At least looking at your comment, I don't see it in the PATH.  Can you add it manually? I don't know how it works on macOs to be honest.

Comment: @TimothyG. I started diving deeper into this PATH stuff and I finally found a soltution [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33303456/23287587)

Comment: @BaldurLogi I followed the instruction on this page (including the step using the tool palette) and all was working after that. I'm on Mac too https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/mac