# Synchronise vertical/horizontal scrolling in split view

Tags: visual-studio-code, horizontal-scrolling, vertical-scrolling

Is there a way in `VS Code` to synchronise vertical or horizontal scrolling in splitted view ?

Like in `Notepad++` for instance :

*From buttons:*

[image: Notepad++ Vertical/Horizontal sync]

*From View menu:*

[image: Notepad++ Vertical/Horizontal sync]

Comment: Looks like it is a feature request, see https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/18137  but not with a lot of momentum other than for markdown previews.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

**2021 EDIT**: While the below does still work, as per @Mr.D.Q's answer below, there does now exist a plugin [Sync Scroll](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dqisme.sync-scroll) to accomplish this task.

--

From what I can find, the closest thing you can do is use the "Compare Files" feature.

In the File-Explorer sidebar:

- Right-click on File A -> Select For Compare
- Right-click on File B -> Compare With Selected

Comment: That's a nice workaround ! I'll mark your answer as accepted, until maybe one day VSCode offers a true way to synchronise vertical and horizontal scrolling.

Comment: This only works for the scenario when you want to compare very similar files. A lot of other times this feature does not work well.

Comment: I just want to emphasize the SIDEBAR EXPLORER and not the top file navigation bar.

Comment: The first answer's the best.
With Sync Scroll, if A file contains more lines than B file, then there is a gap between them.
The native 'Select for Compare' + 'Compare with Selected' is more accurate :)

Comment: Sync Scroll works!

Two issues though:
1. Doesnt work for horizontal scrolling.
2. If you manually horizontal-scroll both files and then scroll vertically, one of the file resets the horizontal scroll back to start.

Answer (score 37):

If you want to more advanced synchronized scrolling feature, please check out this vscode extension [Sync Scroll](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dqisme.sync-scroll)

Answer (score 3):

See issue ticket [Synchronized Scrolling in Split Editor #33110](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/33110). See [the VS Code 1.88 release notes](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_88#_locked-scrolling).

You can use the `View: Toggle Locked Scrolling Across Editors` command. Quoting one of the maintainers (Benjamin) in [their comment](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/33110#issuecomment-1997823266):

> [the command] will synchronize the scrolling across all text editors and notebooks. You can also set a keybinding for workbench.action.holdLockedScrolling which will synchronize the scrolling only when being pressed.

[You can also](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/33110#issuecomment-1997823266) bind a keyboard shortcut to the command ID `workbench.action.holdLockedScrolling`, which will synchronize scrolling only while that keyboard shortcut is being pressed.

Note that you can also use the "select for compare" feature to get a similar effect (see [Visual Studio Code - is there a Compare feature like that plugin for Notepad ++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30139597/11107541)).