# VS Code: How to scroll split panels simultaneously

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to compare similar, but different files in VS Code.

Is it possible to scroll both panes at the same time?

I'm referring to `Editor Groups` in the image below.

This sample image is taken from https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface

[image: VS Code Activity Bar, split panels, Editor Groups, Side Bar, and Status Bar]

Comment: found this for Atom  https://atom.io/packages/scroll-sync

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In the Explorer sidebar:

Right-click on package.json -> Select For Compare

Right-click on findoptionswidget.ts -> Compare With Selected

You can then scroll the two panes simultaneously.

Answer (score 11):

It's a highly requested feature, but there's currently no native way to do this.

But you can download the extension [**Sync Scroll**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dqisme.sync-scroll) which will scroll all open editor panes

[image: demo]

#### Additional Resources

- Stack Overflow - [Synchronise vertical/horizontal scrolling in split view](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45325984/1366033)
- Github - [Synchronized Scrolling in Split Editor](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/33110)
- Github - [Link scrolling in editor split-view](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/34762)

Comment: Sync Scroll works perfectly.  Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately this always jumps to the same line in both files for me, making this basically useless for my use cases. EDIT: nvm just had to switch the mode to OFFSET.