# Can't run the command "install code command in PATH"

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

I am using Visual Studio Code, but I can't run the option "install code command in path", because this command does not appear when I type <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>. I am using Windows 10 and the latest version of Visual Studio Code.

I tried many steps to solve my problem, but with no success. Here is what I did:

1. Reinstalled Visual Studio Code (the latest version), and checked the option to add to the PATH variable. Didn't work.
2. Opened Environment Variables and edited the `Path` user variable, restarted the computer. Didn't work.
3. Opened command prompt and typed `code .`. Didn't work.

What should I do next?

Comment: Are you on a Mac? Did you access the shell first? See the instructions here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/mac

Comment: Possible duplicate of [visual studio code "Shell Command: Install 'code' command in PATH command."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47528373/visual-studio-code-shell-command-install-code-command-in-path-command)

Answer (score 1):

When using Visual Studio Code and:

1. code . does not work
2. "install code command in path" doesn't exist in Visual Studio Code

Manually add VS Code to your path using the following command in Git:

```
cat << EOF >> ~/.bash_profile
# Add Visual Studio Code (code)
export PATH="\$PATH:/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin"
EOF
```

Start a new terminal to pick up your .bash_profile changes.

**Note:** The leading slash \ is required to prevent $PATH from expanding during the concatenation. Remove the leading slash if you want to run the export command directly in a terminal.

**Note:** Since zsh became the default shell in macOS Catalina, run the following commands to add VS Code to your path:

```
cat << EOF >> ~/.zprofile
# Add Visual Studio Code (code)
export PATH="\$PATH:/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin"
EOF
```

Answer (score -1):

With Windows it is installed by default so you don't need to add path. Just run " code . " in cmd and it will work fine