# How to open json file with vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, command-line-arguments

I was watching a course. He uses linux i think. I install node and npm like him. He write atom . to consol and automatically 'server' which we created first is opened. How can i open that server in windows with vscode?

I tried vscode . visual . etc. but it did not work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call VS Code Editor from terminal / command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29963617/how-to-call-vs-code-editor-from-terminal-command-line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have VSCode installed, you can use `code .` to open VSCode in the current directory.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to open it through the terminal and you have the VS Code path installed, you can use:

```
code your_json_file.json
```

If it's not installed, you can follow these steps:

Launch VS Code.
Open the Command Palette (Cmd+Shift+P) and type 'shell command' to find the "Shell Command: Install 'code' command in PATH" command.